# Multiple tags for a Docker image built by Google Jib and Maven?

Tags: jib, maven-jib

Using the `jib-maven-plugin` I'd like to build an image with mulitple tags. While `mvn jib:build` basically works fine, it "only" tags the image with `latest`.

My Maven `pom.xml` defines the following:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <to>
            <image>my-private-registry.org/my-image</image>
        </to>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[The docs](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#build-your-image) show that one can use `jib.to.tags` in the XML to define a list of tags. However, I'd like to run the build step in a Jenkins pipeline, i.e. I cannot hard-code the tags in the `pom.xml`.

Is it possible to pass the list of tags when running the `mvn` command, e.g. by setting some `-D` parameters?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `-Djib.to.tags=a,b,c`.

```
$ mvn package jib:build -Djib.to.tags=a,b,c
...
[INFO] --- jib-maven-plugin:2.8.0:dockerBuild (default-cli) @ hello-spring-boot ---
[INFO] Tagging image with generated image reference hello-spring-boot:0.1.0. If you'd like to specify a different tag, you can set the <to><image> parameter in your pom.xml, or use the -Dimage=<MY IMAGE> commandline flag.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Containerizing application to Docker daemon as hello-spring-boot:0.1.0, hello-spring-boot:a, hello-spring-boot:b, hello-spring-boot:c...
[WARNING] Base image 'gcr.io/distroless/java:8' does not use a specific image digest - build may not be reproducible
[INFO] Using base image with digest: sha256:34c3598d83f0dba27820323044ebe79e63ad4f137b405676da75a3905a408adf
[INFO] 
[INFO] Container entrypoint set to [java, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom, -cp, /app/resources:/app/classes:/app/libs/*, hello.Application]
[INFO] 
[INFO] Built image to Docker daemon as hello-spring-boot:0.1.0, hello-spring-boot:a, hello-spring-boot:b, hello-spring-boot:c
[INFO] 
[INFO] A new version of Jib (3.0.0) is available (currently using 2.8.0). Update your build configuration to use the latest features and fixes!
[INFO] https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-maven-plugin/CHANGELOG.md
[INFO] Please see https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/privacy.md for info on disabling this update check.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Executing tasks:
[INFO] [==============================] 100.0% complete
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have this command:
./mvnw package -Pprod verify -DskipTests jib:build -Dimage=registry.gitlab.com/me/myproject:master
when using -Djib.to.tags=master,v1.14 would it push directly both tags?

Comment: @Alejandro as you are using the -Dimage param and this is anyway not optional, you don´t have to put the master tag in -Djib.to.tags. With the -Djib.to.tags param you can add additional tags to push to.

Comment: I was able to get it using pom configuration, so the command doesn't change. Thanks for the hint though :)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same question and I solved using this snippet in my pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <from>
            <image>${jib-maven-plugin.image}</image>
        </from>
        <to>
            <image>registry.gitlab.com/mygroup/myproject</image>
            <tags>
                <tag>latest</tag>
                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
            </tags>
        </to>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

simply calling `mvn clean package -Pprod verify jib:build` will push both `latest` and the project's version defined in pom