# Use multiple tags when creating Docker image using Spring Boot Maven Plugin

Tags: docker, maven, azure-devops, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using the Spring Boot Maven Plugin to create Docker images. They are tagged with `latest`, but I would like to have 2 tags added to it.

This is my current config:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>myacr.azurecr.io/${project.artifactId}</name>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I would like to have `latest` and a certain build number (which will come from the Azure DevOps pipeline).

Is this possible with the Maven plugin? I could not find any info in the docs about it.

Comment: You can give a custom tag but then image won't be tagged to `latest`.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help but I have found this closed Issue [Apply multiple docker image tags when publishing images](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20560) and this open PR [Add option to create tags for the built image](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/27613/files). So I believe it is not still possible while Spring people is working on it. There is no reference about it in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: Thanks @usuario, seems it is not possible currently indeed.

Comment: Hi @WimDeblauwe, I try to do the same, but am not able to authenticate against azure ACR. I use 1.4.13. Could you tell me how you provided the SPN to the plugin?

Comment: there seems to be a tags attribute, but it has no property to set: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible, not sure since when.

Use the following configuration:

```
            <image>
                <name>myacr.azurecr.io/${project.artifactId}</name>
                <tags>
                    myacr.azurecr.io/${project.artifactId}:${project.version},myacr.azurecr.io/${project.artifactId}:latest
                </tags>
            </image>
```

Docs are here: [Spring Boot Maven Plugin Tags](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization.tags)

No hint in the docs about the comma seperation, but it seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this possible with the Maven plugin? I could not find any info in the docs about it.

Indeed, just as the usuario pointed that the Spring Boot Maven Plugin does not support tagged multiple tags when creating Docker image at this moment.

[Add option to create tags for the built image](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/27613/files)

As workaround, we could use other plugin, like `jib-maven-plugin`：

```
-Djib.to.tags=a,b,c
```

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017380/multiple-tags-for-a-docker-image-built-by-google-jib-and-maven) for some more details.